# Show text inside the image asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image

I have an image in a gridview, [image]

I want dynamic text inside this image. Text I am getting from this way from the database:

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"textForImage")%>
```

but to show inside this buuble? which control i have to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this image as a `background-image` on a `div` and place the text inside the `div` and position it using CSS

```
<div class="bubble">
  <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"textForImage")%>
</div>

.bubble
{
background-image:url(...);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I am getting sevearl small images of that speech bubble and when I changed the property like this .bubble { background-image:url('bubble2.png') no-repeat ; } than no bubble is being displayed.

Comment: have you tried {background-image:url('bubble2.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat} ?

Comment: @Chris: Try specifying the width and height of the buble explicitly in the .bubble CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the background image of a division to the bubble and then create the text inside that division.